# Victor Krum Tri-Wizard tournament performance

Tags: harry-potter

In chapter 20 of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, "The First Task", after the scores are read out for the completion of the first task, Charlie Weasley says:

> ‘You’re tied in first place, Harry! You and Krum!’

I have tabulated the scores that were listed for Harry and Victor below:

[image: A table of Harry and Victor's scores in the first task, showing that Harry Potter received an 8 from Maxime, a 9 from Dumbledore, a 10 from Bagman, and a 4 from Karkaroff, while Victor Krum received a 10 from Karkaroff, with the points from the other judges remaining unknown but adding up so that Harry and Victor are tied at 31 points total each]

Earlier Ron proclaims (emphasis mine):

> ‘What?’ Ron bellowed furiously. ‘Four? You lousy **biased** scumbag, you gave Krum ten!’

I have worked out the other possible score combinations, listed below:

**1 10 10

2 9 10

3 8 10

3 9 9

4 7 10

4 8 9

5 6 10**
5 7 9
5 8 8
6 6 9
6 7 8
7 7 7

The combinations I have made bold would make me think at least one of the three remaining judges was showing bias.

Is there any reference in the canon or any remarks made by Rowling to suggest what the other scores might have been?

Comment: Yeah, go on, do the math on a kids' story... That's not gonna end poorly! ;-)

Comment: Personally I find it more likely that Krum (who's supposed to be pretty sharp) genuinely gave a 7- or 8/10 performance and the other judges scored it accordingly. But given JKR's apathy towards numerical minutiae in general (see also: every single time a date is mentioned) I wouldn't expect there to be a canon explanation.

Comment: J.K. Rowling maths are bad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I have deleted my previous answer, as it was based upon the same incorrect information as the question.*

---

Your question is based upon incorrect information, since there were 5 judges present at the first task. You've missed Barty Crouch sr, who awarded Harry 9 points as well.

So the total number of points Harry received was 40: 8 from Maxime, 9 from Crouch, 9 from Dumbledore, 10 from Bagman, and 4 from Karkaroff.

Since Victor Krum received 10 points from Karkaroff, that leaves 30 points between the remaining four judges, with an average of 7.5 points per judge, which seems entirely reasonable.

And don't forget that Krum got docked some points for damaging the other eggs, as Ron explains to Harry.

> "[...] And Krum - you won't believe this, but he didn't even think of flying! He was probably the best after you, though. Hit it with some sort of spell right in the eye. Only thing is, it went trampling around in agony and squashed half the real eggs - they took marks off for that, he wasn't supposed to do any damage to them."
>
> <sub>—*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* by J.K. Rowling, chapter 20: "The First Task"</sub>

So there seems no foul play going on there, although I wouldn't put it past Bagman to give Krum a lower score than was strictly fair. After all, he offered Harry his help right before the start of the task.

---

In the second task, Cedric scores 47 points, Harry 45, Krum 40, and Fleur 25. This leaves Harry now tied with Cedric at 85 points, with Krum in third place at 80 points and Fleur last, her total score still unkown.
From this we can deduce that Cedric had scored 38 points in the first task.

Comment: It was only when I was in the process of asking a follow-up question how they picked up an additional 9 points, that I found out both the querant and I had overlooked Crouch sr. and the points he gave.